# Set required iOS SDK version in podspec?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

Anyone know of a way to set a required SDK version in a CocoaPod podspec? I'd like to set a requirement of the iOS 8 SDK while deploying back to iOS 6.

Comment: Can you describe more on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to require a a certain SDK version in the podspec. Ideally it would cause either the pod install or project build to fail if the base SDK isn't at least that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use platform in pod spec to specify the version. For   Example

```
spec.platform     = :ios, "7.0"
```